# SpringBoot Test, inject value in configuration

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, dependency-injection, testcontainers

What Im' trying to do:

- start MongoDB Container from test containers https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-spring-boot/tree/develop/embedded-mongodb
- Inject MongoDB uri taken from started container into Configuration
- Run test

Here is my code:

```java
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
        "embedded.mongodb.install.enabled=true",
        "spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://${embedded.mongodb.host}:${embedded.mongodb.port}/${embedded.mongodb.database}"
})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ImportAutoConfiguration
class UploadFileControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private static MongoDBContainer mongoDbContainer;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void startContainer() {
        mongoDbContainer = new MongoDBContainer();

        mongoDbContainer.start();
        // !!! this one should be injected into spring.data.mongodb.uri
        System.out.println("mongoURL: " + mongoDbContainer.getReplicaSetUrl());
        // !!!
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void stopContainer() {
        mongoDbContainer.stop();
    }

    @Test
    void testUploadAndParseFile() throws Exception {
        var fileUploadTask = uploadFileUsingMockMvc(zipFile);
        System.out.println(fileUploadTask);
    }
}
```

I cant' find a way to populate `spring.data.mongodb.uri` configuration value.

Comment: Check out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb

Comment: I want the real one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using JUnit 5, you can use a JUnit Jupiter extension for Testcontainers, so you don't have to manually start and stop them (like `@ClassRule` in JUnit 4):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
  <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and if you use Spring Boot >= 2.2.6 they even simplified the way to set properties dynamically in a test using `@DynamicPropertySource`.

If you combine both, your test can look like the following:

```
// @ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class}) not needed, already part of @SpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ImportAutoConfiguration
@Testcontainers // this is new
class UploadFileControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Container
    private static MongoDBContainer mongoDbContainer = new MongoDBContainer();

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void mongoDbProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
      registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri", mongoDbContainer::getUri);
    }


    @Test
    void testStuffWithMongo() throws Exception {
     // bla-bla-bla
    }
}
```

If you are using JUnit 4 or a version of Spring Boot before 2.2.6, I've collected different setup methods [here](https://rieckpil.de/howto-write-spring-boot-integration-tests-with-a-real-database/).

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution, it smells a bit since it has global static state, but it works at least

Wrap container

```java
public class MongoDbContainerEntryPoint {

    private static MongoDBContainer mongoDbContainer = new MongoDBContainer();

    public static void start() {
        mongoDbContainer.start();
    }

    public static void stop() {
        mongoDbContainer.stop();
    }

    public static String getUri() {
        return mongoDbContainer.getReplicaSetUrl();
    }
}
```

This thing allows to override properties during test instantiation

```java
public class MongoDBContextInitializer implements
        ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ac) {

        ConfigurableEnvironment ce = ac.getEnvironment();
        System.out.println("Setting to configuration: " + MongoDbContainerEntryPoint.getUri());
        TestPropertyValues values = TestPropertyValues.of(
                "spring.data.mongodb.uri=" + MongoDbContainerEntryPoint.getUri()
        );
        values.applyTo(ac);
    }
}
```

Here is the test

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = MongoDBContextInitializer.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ImportAutoConfiguration
class UploadFileControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    @BeforeAll
    public static void startContainer() {
        MongoDbContainerEntryPoint.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void stopContainer() {
        MongoDbContainerEntryPoint.stop();
    }

    @Test
    void testStuffWithMongo() throws Exception {
     // bla-bla-bla
    }
}
```